# Repetitive variable declaration in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

I wonder how JS engine handles variable declaration in ES6 like:

No matter:

```
let V1 = "let Hello";
const V1 = "const Hello";
V1 = "reassigned Hello"
```

Or:

```
const V1 = "const Hello";
let V1 = "let Hello";
V1 = "reassigned Hello"
```

V1 is always "reassigned Hello"

I thought if a variable declared with **const**, then it should not be reassign value. Why it works?

Comment: It should throw a pretty clear error if you run that snippet. Are you sure running these works for you? And if so, where?

Comment: @loganfsmyth When I troed React tutorial( https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html ) on codepen,  I accidentally use code like :      let status;
    const status = "CONST VARIABLE"
    if (winner) {
      status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
    } else {
      status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
    }
it eventually shows "Winner is X" or "Winner is O"

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Codepen then. Best to test out JS snippets in the browser console or by creating a file to run in Node or something.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks, and Yes, it throws error in Chrome console ( and it shows error on codepen too now). I am not sure why it ran on codepen just now

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in the comments that you were following the [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and using their CodePen example.

This Pen is setup to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) which transpiles the ES6 code into ES5, so the reason your assignment works is because this:

```
let V1 = "let Hello";
const V1 = "const Hello";
```

Is actually transpiled and executed as this:

```
var V1 = "let Hello";
var V1 = "const Hello";
```

If you disable Babel for the Pen and use a browser that supports `const` natively (i.e. any modern browser) you’ll see an exception.

Answer (score -1):

If you test this in Chrome for example you will get 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'V1' has already been declared`

[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIVfg.png)